# Post metafields to shopify admin API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, shopify

I´m trying to save customers metafields using the shopify admin api, i´m using this code

```
var data = {
    "metafield": {
        "namespace": "test",
        "key": "testkey",
        "value": "lorem ipsum",
        "value_type": "string"
    }
}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/admin/customers/0000000000/metafields.json", true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa('myuser:mypass'));
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data)); //RETURNS A CODE 301 WITHOUT RESPONSE MESSAGE
xhr.send(data); //RETURNS A CODE 400 WITH "error 419: unexpected token at 'object Object]'" MESSAGE
```

Please tell me What I missing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))` is the correct method. The 301 response from that indicates that the request was redirected, which would imply that the URL you're calling is not correct

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to save the metadata to customer id 00000000 in your URL, typically you'll want to have that field supplied dynamically if this is going to be used in a utility tool. Your probably might be that ID is not pointing at an actual customer ID.